# Texture trimming library?

Tags: algorithm, graphics

Is there any algorithm or open source library for trimming texture?
The trimming texture means, generate a polygon that cutting off transparent part from a texture.

Here is an example from [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Performance/Performance.html).
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the convex hull of non-transparent pixels?

Comment: @NicoSchertler I thought about that. I think, that algorithm do not fit for this case. Because the candidate points are too many and their density is too high. Therefore the convex hull will be just a outline of image, not a polygon. If use that algorithm, another algorithm that reducing density of candidate points needed.

Comment: This kind of oversampling might only occur on boundary pixels that lie on the convex hull. So, the result will usually not be just the outline of the image (unless it is already convex). You could add a simplification step afterwards to get rid of them. And this simplification does not seem to be too hard.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Yes, It may works nicely in some cases such as Apple doc shown. However, I also worried about concave, holes and multi-fragments such as atlas texture, not just convex shapes. In the end, achieved a result that the HACD algorithm using in 3D could be an answer.